# Algorithm to evaluate best weights for weighted average

Tags: algorithm, average

I have a data set of the form:

[9.1 5.6 7.4] => 8.5, [4.1 4.4 5.2] => 4.9, ... , x => y(x)

So x is a real vector of three elements and y is a scalar function.

I'm assuming a weighted average model of this data:

y(x) = (a * x[0] + b * x[1] + c * x[2]) / (a+b+c) + E(x)

where E is an unknown random error term.

I need an algorithm to find a,b,c, that minimizes total sum square error:

error = sum over all x of { E(x)^2 }

for a given data set.

Comment: Why do you need an algorithm for this ? I mean it's straight forward as you wrote it in math

Comment: I'm creating some recommendation system and I need it in my own java app ;)

Comment: You never defined y(x).   Are you saying the dataset pairs are x => y and a,b,c are the weights and you are trying to find a,b,c that best match (provide least error sum) the dataset?

Comment: Yeah, that's all about. I've made an update to top post ;)

Comment: Could you live with stripping the normalization away (`/(a+b+c)`) and with a, b, c not adding up to 1 in every case? If so, it can be done with a simple least squares solver which requires a bit of matrix math and solving a 3x3 linear system of equations (which could be hard-coded if necessary).

Comment: I'll look into that, 3 variables was only example, in my case there will be 7 vars, but that shouldn't be the problem (other than performance i hope)

Comment: For 7 variables, it is a 7x7 system. Then you should use a math library that can solve such equations. You could also try other (non-linear) optimization methods (such as Levenberg-Marquardt) if you want to keep the normalization. Or a constrained least-squares solver.

Comment: The close votes are premature.  He's using math notation for vector algebra.  The question is actually well-posed. I edited to make it a bit clearer for non-mathematicians.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Least-squares_estimation_and_related_techniques)

Comment: @Kicsi It's not exactly a linear regression, but closely related.

Comment: Do you know some lib to java, that could solve those equations? For linear regression I know that weka can do some useful things :)

Comment: By writing `E(x)`, you are implying that the error term is a function of the `x` vector.  Is that what you really meant? Also, is your objective to come up with an unbiased estimate `y(x)` of some characteristic you haven't specified? Do you have observations of `y(x)` that you're trying to match with your function?

Comment: I have observations of y(x) for each x in dataset and try to  estimate such a,b,c.. that minimize total error between observed y(x) and calculated using a,b,c (let's call that estimated function f(x)) so E(x) = y(x) - f(x)

Comment: We still need to know whether the residuals (error terms) have distributions that depend on the `x` or not.

Comment: If you lose the scaling factor `1 / (a + b + c)`, this is least squares regression. If the variance of the residuals changes as a function of `y`, you should apply a variance stabilizing transformation to the `y`'s such as sqrt(y) or log(y). If variance changes as a function of `x`, you want [weighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Weighted_least_squares), where the optimal weights are inversely proportional to the variance of the residuals. Scaling makes this harder and you haven't given us the context of your question. Is the scaling really necessary?

Comment: Can you address @pjs's question? Your notation shows an error that depends on the observation matrix, but you mention that it is "random and unknown". If this is true, then `error = sum over all x of { E(x)^2 }` is unknown as well and cannot be minimized. Do you mean the sum of squares of `(prediction[i]-observation[i])`? In this case, and assuming that `E(x)=E~N(μ,σ)` and `X.min<= Y <=X.max` for each observation, I believe your model is an ordinary linear regression with zero constant term.

Comment: Those "random and unknown" error is sth that @Gene added during his edition to the topic. What I need is exactly minimization of `(prediction[i]-observation[i])` and you're also right that `X[i]` as well as `Y` has limitation and should be in `[0, 10]`, that's why I wanted to use weighted average for that.

Comment: @loannis  It is random and unknown _with respect to the linear model_.  The drill on regression analysis of this type is to make an assumption about the form of data.  This is the model.  Then set out to minimize the difference between the data and the model by finding the best possible model parameters.  See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Oh I see. If Y falls always between the Xs (which is not the sane as always being in [0,10] , just OLS will give you what you want. Your constant term will turn up as zero and the coefficients should add up to 1. I can't justify this now (I'm in mobile), but if you had 2 dimensional X and Y in bbetween, the error minimizing  predictor should be in the range `[X.min,X.Max]`

Comment: @pjs It's still least squares.  You just need to express the last coefficient in terms of all the others and then solve for those others.

Comment: @Gene It's still least squares in principle, but it may be over-constrained by the convexity requirement. For instance, in your answer below, you ended up deriving a negative coefficient, which violates convexity.

Comment: @Ioannis what does OLS mean? :)

Comment: @Gene I absolutely agree with you, but the phrasing of the question, as a whole (not the part you added) was wrong. The model error is indeed iid normal with constant variance, but the question mixes the model error with the observed error as it is written

Comment: @wajs [Ordinary Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).

Comment: Thx. I just realized that my first idea of weighted mean is not the best, as it doesn't transform X to [0,10] but to [X.min,X.max], and my observations can be in [0,10]. Does OLS or linear regression or sth else provide limitation of output value?

Comment: @wajs My answer is exactly OLS with the restriction that a+b+c=1.  You can easily remove that restriction.  Note I added a test with some randomly generated data to show how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that the weights are normalized to sum to 1 (which happily is without loss of generality), then we can re-cast the problem with c = 1 - a - b, so we are actually solving for a and b.

With this we can write

```
error(a,b) = sum over all x { a x[0] + b x[1] + (1 - a - b) x[2] - y(x) }^2
```

Now it's just a question of taking the partial derivatives d_error/da and d_error/db and setting them to zero to find the minimum.

With some fiddling, you get a system of two equations in a and b.

```
C(X[0],X[0],X[2]) a + C(X[0],X[1],X[2]) b = C(X[0],Y,X[2])
C(X[1],X[0],X[2]) a + C(X[1],X[1],X[2]) b = C(X[1],Y,X[2])
```

The meaning of X[i] is the vector of all i'th components from the dataset x values.

The meaning of Y is the vector of all y(x) values.

The coefficient function C has the following meaning:

```
C(p, q, r) = sum over i { p[i] ( q[i] - r[i] ) }
```

I'll omit how to solve the 2x2 system unless this is a problem.

If we plug in the two-element data set you gave, we should get precise coefficients because you can always approximate two points perfectly with a line.  So for example the first equation coefficients are:

```
C(X[0],X[0],X[2]) =  9.1(9.1 - 7.4) + 4.1(4.1 - 5.2) = 10.96
C(X[0],X[1],X[2]) = -19.66
C(X[0],Y,X[2]) = 8.78
```

Similarly for the second equation: 4.68 -13.6   4.84

Solving the 2x2 system produces:  a = 0.42515, b = -0.20958.  Therefore c = 0.78443.

Note that in this problem a negative coefficient results.  There is nothing to guarantee they'll be positive, though "real" data sets may produce this result.

Indeed if you compute weighted averages with these coefficients, they are 8.5 and 4.9.

For fun I also tried this data set:

```
X[0]        X[1]        X[2]        Y
0.018056028 9.70442075  9.368093544 6.360312244
8.138752835 5.181373099 3.824747424 5.423581239
6.296398214 4.74405298  9.837741509 7.714662742
5.177385358 1.241610571 5.028388255 4.491743107
4.251033792 8.261317658 7.415111851 6.430957844
4.720645386 1.0721718   2.187147908 2.815078796
1.941872069 1.108191586 6.24591771  3.994268819
4.220448549 9.931055481 4.435085917 5.233711923
9.398867623 2.799376317 7.982096264 7.612485261
4.971020963 1.578519218 0.462459906 2.248086465
```

I generated the Y values with `1/3 x[0] + 1/6 x[1] + 1/2 x[2] + E` where E is a random number in [-0.1..+0.1].  If the algorithm is working correctly we'd expect to get roughly a = 1/3 and b = 1/6 from this result.  Indeed we get a = .3472 and b = .1845.

OP has now said that his actual data are larger than 3-vectors.  This method generalizes without much trouble. If the vectors are of length n, then you get an n-1 x n-1 system to solve.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't true in general, it only applies if the original weights sum to one or to scaled values `a* = a / (a + b + c)`, `b* = b / (a + b + c)`, `c* = c / (a + b + c)`. It's unlikely that the original weights sum to one -- there'd be no need for scaling in the original problem statement if `[a,b,c]` already represented convex weights.

Comment: You're right I should have re-named a,b,c as you say.  Since all weight sets that differ by a constant factor are optimal wrt his definition, we can just assume we're looking for normalized coefficients.  I added this.  Thanks.